# Populate list items from json in React component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm new to `reactjs` and i have a `json` object that i want to iterate through and populate list items in a react component. I get the `json` from server with an `ajax` call..

My ajax inside getData() method:

```
  $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'get',
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({ data: JSON.parse(data) })  //or parse
            }.bind(this)
        },

    );
```

Constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: null
    };

    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }
```

Data looks like this:

```
{
    "commentID":25,
    "matchID":43234,
    "commentatorID":12537228724216704,
    "timeM":67,
    "timeRT":null,
    "action":"goal",
    "description":"aaaaaaaa"
},
{
    "commentID":27,
    "matchID":56,
    "commentatorID":12537228724216704,
    "timeM":14,
    "timeRT":null,
    "action":"",
    "description":"fgfafafaaffaafasfasf"
},
```

What i've already tried is to stringify the `object` but when i try to iterate through the `string`, it's alot of work when i only want to list "description" and "timeM" .

Should i run through the `json` object in the `render` method and create list items or are there other ways to do it? I'm looking for a good example on how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand which react component life-cycle events one should **setState** in, you could refer to
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

to create the new array, you could simply

```
this.setState({
    data: resoponseArray.map(item => {description: item.description, timeM: item.timeM})
})
```

Edit

and to render you data

```
render () {
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.data.map((item, key) => {
                        return <li key={key}>{item.timeM} {item.description}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is you have to loop over the array response more than once. It would be better to just store the object and then loop over one time in the render. Since all you are really doing is just storing the same thing just a few less keys.. You should change your answer to include how to render the items in a list with a map

Comment: thank you! But, for some reason i get unexpected token after timeM in this.setState. any idea why? it want me to put " ; " there, but thats obviously wrong.

Comment: the responeArray is the data collected from the success callback right?

Comment: when i console.log the Data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. So that is the structure.

Comment: No what I was describing is what I knew the edited answer would show `.map` is used both once at the setState on the ajax callback and then in the render method. You don't need to map in the set state. Just do this. `this.setState({data: JSON.parse(data)})` that removes the need for the extra unnecessary loop